# MongoDB, multiple query with the same req.query in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to query (with the same **req.query**) on **multiple collections**, with express and mongodb (native driver).

I am using **async.parallel** for this, the problem is that in **res.render** I cannot get **locals** in **users**,(`users:locals`) users subsequently it is in a for loop in an ejs page.

```
router.get('/search', function (req, res){

if (!req.query.name)
return res.render("search", {
  users:[],
  title: "Mongo Search",
  query: "",
});

else {
var query = req.query.name;

 MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
  const db = client.db('local');
  const collection = db.collection('oneCollections');
  const collection2 = db.collection('twoCollections');

  var locals = {};
  var tasks = [
    function(callback) {

  collection.find({ firstname: { $regex: query, $options: 'i' }}).toArray(function(names){   
    locals.names= names;
                    callback(); 
});

    },
    function(callback) {

      collection2.find({ emailaddress: { $regex: query, $options: 'i' }}).toArray(function( emails){    
        locals.emails = emails;
                    callback();
    });
    
  }

  ];

  

  async.parallel(tasks, function() {
locals = {names:[locals.names], emails:[local.emails]}

res.render('search', { users:locals, title: "Mongo Search",query: "", });
  });
});
}
    });

module.exports = router;
```

how could i solve this problem? it seems that the object `locals = {names:[locals.names], emails:[local.emails]}`**local** cannot store the properties of search queries made in callbacks.
or something else wrong?
thanks for any clarification!

Comment: Bad practice. do no connect on every request to the db. you can reuse a existing connection for multiple querys. `locals = { names: [locals.names], emails: [local.emails] }` the square brackets are "useless". you create here a array out of a arrray (locals.names) just to create a object from a object. Terrible and unclean

Comment: there was a transcription error regarding the square brackets.I asked the question on purpose, to find out how best to act